# Qt Creator on Mac, vertical selection possible (without mouse)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qt-creator

How to do vertical selection to edit multiple lines at the same time?

I tried Shift+alt (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7773) but do not seems to work here.

In Windows I used to do that with Alt+Shift on Qt Creator and Ctrl+Alt on Sublime 2.

Comment: On Windows and Linux I am using Alt without Shift (and mouse). Did you try it?

Comment: on OS X holding `alt` in Qt Creator do the job.

Comment: @Marek R, which Qt Creator version? I have Qt Creator 4 in El Captain and here `alt+up` goes to to the beginning of the word while `alt+down`  goes to the end.

Comment: Qt Creator 3.5, OS X El Capitan. `alt` and selecting area by mouse is working (when using only keyboard doesn't work).